# How to connect multiple base classes to multiple subclasses through single interface in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, subclass

I've got three classes that inherit from a higher base class that we'll call UpperCaseLetters. Therein there are classes LetterA, LetterB, and LetterC. I wish to build an interface to connect them each to respective subclasses LowerA, LowerB, and LowerC. I have one interface that has a single property "UpperCaseLetter" that effectively stores or references the corresponding uppercase letter. This is fine for when I want to construct a single object of known type at the lower case letter level, because I can just as easily cite the uppercase letter manually.

I need to build a script that is capable of looking at my existing set of uppercase letters, and build a corresponding lowercase letter object by implementing the interface, such that I end up with a lowercase letter object, such as LowerA, that implements the property from the interface referencing the LetterA object it is attached to.

In C#, iterating through a loop, when I come across an item that does not appear to have a matching LowerCaseLetter object, how can use type information from the UpperCaseLetter subclass (LetterA, LetterB, or LetterC) to dynamically construct a corresponding LowerCaseLetter object of the respective LowerCaseLetter subclass (LowerA, LowerB, or LowerC) without statically listing out the types of subclasses in each letter case available?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
class UpperCaseLetter {
public bool Italic
}

class LetterA : UpperCaseLetter {

}

class LetterB : UpperCaseLetter {

}

interface LowerCaseLetter {
    public UpperCaseLetter OriginalLetter;
}

class LowerA : LetterA, LowerCaseLetter { 

}

class LowerB : LetterB, LowerCaseLetter {

}


void BuildLowerCaseLetters {
    foreach (var upperLetter in setOfImaginaryBuiltLetterObjects){
        //below is how the code currently works, but any time I build a new pair of 
        //classes, say, LetterD and LowerD, this section needs to be modified. 
        //Looking for a dynamic solution
        if (upperLetter is LetterA){
            new LowerA();
        } else if (upperLetter is LetterB){
            new LowerB();
        } 
    }   

}
```

Comment: Can you include some code to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but "connected" is an ambiguous term in this question. There are various ways in which classes can be related; please use the right one, so that other engineers will know what you're talking about. If you haven't figured out the right word for it, maybe you haven't thought about the problem enough. I would suggest that there is no inheritance relationship between "UppercaseLetter" and "LowercaseLetter" as they are mutually exclusive, although they potentially could both inherit from simply "Letter."

Comment: Why separate `Letter` to `LowerCase` and `UpperCase`? I'm sure the actual code you are working on is different, but if the classes are so tight, perhaps it's better to redesign a single class that can treat both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not treat both upper case and lowercase letters as interfaces and just have a method on the interface to convert between.

```
public interface IUpperCaseLetter
{
    ILowerCaseLetter ToLowerCase();
}

public interface ILowerCaseLetter
{
    IUpperCaseLetter ToUpperCase();
}

public class UpperA : IUpperCaseLetter
{
    public ILowerCaseLetter ToLowerCase()
    {
        return new LowerA();
    }
}

public class LowerA : ILowerCaseLetter
{
    public IUpperCaseLetter ToUpperCase()
    {
        return new UpperA();
    }
}

foreach (var upperLetter in setOfImaginaryBuiltLetterObjects)
{
     var lowerLetter = upperLetter.ToLowerCase();
}
```

Interfaces can also inherit others, so if you have something shared between upper and lower case make a shared interface

```
public interface ILetter
{
    bool Italic{ get; }
}

public interface IUpperCaseLetter : ILetter
{
    ILowerCaseLetter ToLowerCase();
}

public interface ILowerCaseLetter : ILetter
{
    IUpperCaseLetter ToUpperCase();
}
```